# Python 2.7 ImportError: No module named numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, windows-10

I trying to run a program in python 2.7 that uses numpy but it gives me the error `ImportError: No module named numpy`. I am using Windows 10. I tried running `pip install numpy` and it says it was installed but I still can't run the program.

Comment: Do you only have python 2.7 installed on the machine or do you have both?

Comment: @Goralight only python 2.7

Comment: How are you running it? Give us the example. The problem may be there. Where does this error occur?

Comment: I'm running my program through pyscripter and the error occurs as soon as I run it

Answer (score 0):

I think **Pip** installed your package for **Python3**.

That's why your  **python** can't find **Numpy**

If you want to use **NumPy** for **Python2** you must install directly ***1.13.3*** **cp27** version, or you must install Python3.

You can check NumPy and Python versions here.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy

My personal advice is to use Python3. It's not a good time to use Python2 I think.

You can check some resources

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html

https://www.activestate.com/blog/2017/01/python-3-vs-python-2-its-different-time

Comment: I've downloaded the 1.13.3 cp27 file but how do I install it?

Comment: I don't know how to install it on Windows machine, but I highly recommend you to install Python3 and then install Numpy, it will solve your poblem